# Does using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] reset the session?

Tags: php

I am finding that the session value is being reset each time I submit the form. The snippet is as follows:

```
 <? php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if($_SESSION['idi']=="")
{
$_SESSION['idi'] = $_GET['id6'];
$_SESSION['class1'] = $_GET['class6'];
$_SESSION['section1'] = $_GET['section6'];
}
echo $_SESSION['idi'].' '.$_SESSION['class1'].' '.$_SESSION['section1'].'<br>';
print session_id(); 
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<table>
<tr>
    <td> <label> CLASS NAME </label>
    <td><input type="text" name="class_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['class1'] ;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label> SECTION </label>
    <td><input type="text" name="section" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['section1'] ;?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" name="update1" >
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update1'])){
        $class_name = $_POST['class_name'];
        $section = $_POST['section'];
        update_data($_SESSION['idi'],$_POST['class_name'],$_POST['section']);
        echo 'did='.$_SESSION['idi'].' class1='.$_SESSION['class1'].' section1='.$_SESSION['section1'].'<br>';
    }

function update_data($id1,$class1,$section1)
    {
        echo'suresh <br>';
        echo $id1.' '.$class1.' '.$section1.'<br>';
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cce')
                    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM class";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
                    or die("Error connecting to database1");

        //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        //{
            echo'TEST<br>';
            $query="UPDATE class SET class_name='".$class1."', class_section='".$section1."' WHERE id = '".$id1."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query)
                    or die("Error connecting to database2");
            echo'TEST2<br>';
        //}
        mysqli_close($dbc); 
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is each time I submit the form, I am expecting to see the same session value printed out. BUT as soon as I hit submit, the value disappears and prints nothing...
However IF I MAKE action="" in the form THEN each time I submit the form the value of `$_SESSION['abc']` is still the same, 99.

Why is this? Does `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` reset the session? Or is it anything in the configuration?

Comment: You really need to post some code (perhaps the form in question). That said, using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] won't touch any $_SESSION variables, so the problem must lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `action=""` then the url to which the form is redirected is the exact url that is currently in location bar. If however, you use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, the url is stripped of any variables, so $_GET['id'] is empty.

Also it should be `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` or `echo  "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";`

Answer (score 1):

PHP_SELF doesn't include GET variables; you need to specify them explicitly (plus change your quotes a bit):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".urlencode($_GET['id']); ?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, But then why does it work when I have action="" in the from tag...It works in this case..

Comment: @Vinay because a "" action submits the form to the exact same URL as it is found in, i.e. GET variables and all.  But use anything else than "", and you have to specify everything.  It's just the way it works, really.

Comment: I get your point. The workaround is fine. But my real worry is why is it that the session variable being reset...

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not close the `<form>` tag -- are you closing the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you're submitting the form to this page, right?  And when it gets back to this page, it runs across `session_start();`, and dutifully restarts the session.  At least that's how I read [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

You might try moving your `session_start();` to the inside of your `if` statement.  That way, it'll only restart the session if it doesn't see that particular session variable.

Alternatively, you can used a named session and pass that along via a cookie, POST, or GET variable.

Comment: That's not how sessions work in PHP. You need to run `session_start()` before you can access session variables.

Comment: Without `session_start` the `$_SESSION` array doesn't exist.  From the PHP manual: "`session_start()` creates a session or resumes [a session]".

Comment: Hi Kyle,But then now does it work when I make action="" in the form tag

Comment: Okay, then what about wrapping the 'session_start' in a 'if( !is_set($_SESSION) )' block?

Comment: @Vinay, I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you omit the 'action', then it just posts to the exact same page you're on now, instead of stripping out your current URL variables like the action you had before.

Comment: Kyle, <?php
session_start();
// store session data
$_SESSION['views']=1;
?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "Pageviews=". $_SESSION['views'];
?>

</body>
</html> that work every time I refresh..With out resetting the session value..I am confused..

Comment: @Kyle: "wrapping the 'session_start' in a 'if( !is_set($_SESSION) )' block" would make no sense.

Comment: Kyle, would you believe if I said that i had put <? php instead of <?php so the sessions did not start...

Answer (score 0):

PHP_SELF has nothing to do with sessions. There must be something wrong in your code.

What i would do is:

```
$Value = '';
if(isset($_GET['myValue']) {
    $Value = $_GET['myValue'];
}
if(!empty($_POST)&&isset($_POST['myValue']) {
    //Do stuff here
}

<form action="<? php echo "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="myValue" value="<?php echo $Value;?>" />
```